# Calling asmx web service using JQuery with parameters causes 500 error

Tags: c#, web-services, jquery, asmx

I have a simple enough web service:

```
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        [WebMethod]
        public string GetToken(string a)
        {
        }
```

And I'm calling it client side using JQuery:

```
    $.ajax({
        post: 'GET',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '../url/GetToken',
        data: "{'a':'test'}",
        success: function (data) {
        },
        error: function (a, b, c) {
        }
    });
```

The call always fails and the error returned is 500 Internal Server Error. I have placed a breakpoint inside the web service, and the code isn't being reached at all. When I modify the web service to take no arguments at all (and remove the `data` element from the JQuery call) the call succeeds. I have played around with different ways to pass the `data` element; I've passed a JSON object (no quotes), and I've removed the quotes from around the `a` argument. None of it works.

### Edit:

Using Fiddler I have determined that the actual error causing the 500 is "Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter".

### Edit 2:

Passing data this way works:

```
data: "a='test'"
```

I have no idea why. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you returning anything in the GetToken method, just not showing it?

Comment: @Decker97 - Yes I am. The web service returns a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haven't tested this, but in your code snippet you have `post: 'GET'` rather than `type: 'GET'`.  That may be causing the server to reject the contentType as json (which is why your data isn't being serialized properly).

Comment: I can't believe I missed that! Thanks!

Comment: Classic case of staring at the same code for too long...happens to me all the time.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a tool like [Fidler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to check the response you are getting back. Most likely there is an error page being returned, but since it is a jquery ajax call you are not seeing it.

Comment: Did as you asked. The actual error is "Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter"

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't use the GET, had to use POST as type, and my web service is in the same directory, but this worked:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'url.asmx/GetToken',
        data: "{'a':'test'}",
        success: function(data) {
            alert("Success");
        },
        error: function(a) {
            alert(a.responseText);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I just did that and here's what I got: **"An attempt was made to call the method ..... using a GET request, which is not allowed."**, even though I changed the type to 'POST'.

Comment: Also note that I put the .asmx extension on the page name.

Comment: Yeah I have it in mine as well. This is really weird :(